# Struggling with promises when using Bridge.NET

Tags: bridge.net

**UPDATE:** Added Deck.NET sample https://deck.net/d6ad74332cfdee1293a535daf5afc144

I am using ImmortalDB which returns a promise: https://github.com/gruns/ImmortalDB#get as follows:

```cs
public class OzCrGbSearchParameterDataManagerData
{
    private const string KEY_PREFIX = "OzCrGbSearchParameterDataManagerData"; //Avoid potential key name collisions
    private const int UNSET_ID = -111; //This is the same as OzCpPlatformConstants.UNSET_ID
    private const string IMMORTAL_DATABASE_NAME = "dbSearchParameterData";

    public OzCrGbSearchParameterDataManagerData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OzCrGbSearchParameterDataManagerData Constructor");
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///     Holds the session for Departing city selected parameter
    /// </summary>
    public int ShipId
    {
        //get => Convert.ToInt32(JavaScriptGetMethod("ShipId", Convert.ToString(UNSET_ID)));
        get
        {
           var blah = JavaScriptGetMethod("ShipId", Convert.ToString(UNSET_ID));
            Console.WriteLine("Blah");
            Console.WriteLine(blah);
            Console.WriteLine("/Blah");
            return -1;
        }

        set => JavaScriptSetMethod("ShipId", Convert.ToString(value));
    }

    private string JavaScriptGetMethod(string aKeyName, string aKeyValueDefault, string aKeyPrefix = KEY_PREFIX)
    {
        return Script.Write<string>("ImmortalDB.ImmortalDB.get('aKeyName', 'aKeyValueDefault')");
    }

    private void JavaScriptSetMethod(string aKeyName, string aKeyValue, string aKeyPrefix = KEY_PREFIX)
    {
        Script.Write("ImmortalDB.ImmortalDB.set('aKeyPrefix.aKeyName', 'aKeyValue');");
    }
}
```

Now what I ultimately see as JS is the following:

[image]

So clearly I am getting a promise back (as expected), but I cannot work out how I change JavaScriptGetMethod either with a combination of return type Task and/or the actual JS it is building so that I get back the **result** of the promise.

Similairly my JavaScriptSetMethod() is not working either.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Bridge.NET nor it's `Script.Write<T>` method, however I hope the below will at least point you in the right direction in case this is still of any actuality.

Think of a Promise as a package you ordered from somewhere and the delivery man just placed in your hands.

You've been holding the box, but it's not the box itself you are interested in, you want whatever it (the box) holds inside. What must you do to get your hands on the item? Open the box (unwrap it) of course.

You can **unwrap** the **Promise** by **await**-ing it or supplying **resolve/reject** handlers. The two functions below showcase the techniques ([Full Deck.NET sample](https://deck.net/4a9292db47fd668575d630523ea884f7))

```cs
    private string JavaScriptGetMethodUnwrapPromise1(string aKeyName, string aKeyValueDefault, string aKeyPrefix = KEY_PREFIX)
    {
        return Script.Write<string>("(async () => { try { const res = await ImmortalDB.ImmortalDB.get('aKeyName', 'aKeyValueDefault'); return JSON.stringify(res); } catch (err) { return JSON.stringify(err); } })();");
    }
```

The above wraps the call to `ImmortalDB.ImmortalDB.get` in a self-executing **async** function, because the **await** keyword can only be used in **async** functions. It then stringifies the return because we want a string not an object.

```cs
    private string JavaScriptGetMethodUnwrapPromise2(string aKeyName, string aKeyValueDefault, string aKeyPrefix = KEY_PREFIX) {
        return Script.Write<string>("(() => { ImmortalDB.ImmortalDB.get('aKeyName', 'aKeyValueDefault').then((res) => { return JSON.stringify(res); }).catch((err) => { return JSON.stringify(err); }); })();");
    }
```

Here we achieve the same, but without an **async** wrapper because we are not **await**-ing the promise but rather attach **resolve/reject** handlers to it.